# NLTK: How can I extract information based on sentence maps?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

I know you can use noun extraction to get nouns out of sentences but how can I use sentence overlays/maps to take out phrases?

**For example:**

> **Sentence Overlay:**
>
> ```
> "First, @action; Second, Foobar"
> ```
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
> "First, Dance and Code; Second, Foobar"
> ```
>
> **I want to return:**
>
> ```
> action = "Dance and Code"
> ```

- Normal Noun Extractions wont work because it wont always be nouns
- The way sentences are phrased differs so it cant be words[x] ... because the positioning of the words changes

Comment: What does the classifier have to do with this task?

Comment: I want to classify an input then pull variables from the input using the map of @ variables in the training data

Comment: Do you know what "classify an input" means? What classification are you after?

Comment: More broadly, I want to use naive Bayes to classify an input to get the action wanted. Eg: "Remind me to do x at y" => reminder.set. Then I want to find x and y

Comment: Great idea, go for it.

Comment: @alexis I know how to classify, but naive Bayes doesent classify to each different phrasing of the same input. "Remind me about x when it's y" and "remind me to x when it's y" are different phrasing of the same task but both will result in "reminder.set". Is there some way I can get the closest phrasing then use the @ maps in the training data to get X and y?

Comment: I recommend you edit the irrelevant stuff out of your question-- who cares you used a classifier in the previous step? It just confuses things. Anyway probably Levenshtein distance is what you need. Or you could convert your templates into regexps and see which one matches -- but this only gives you all-or-nothing matches.

Comment: @alexis Thankyou for the advice on editing. I will look into levenshtein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly rewrite your string templates to turn them into regexps, and see which one (or which ones) match.

```
>>> template = "First, (?P<action>.*); Second, Foobar"
>>> mo = re.search(template, "First, Dance and Code; Second, Foobar")
>>> if mo:
        print(mo.group("action"))
Dance and Code
```

You can even transform your existing strings into this kind of regexp (after escaping regexp metacharacters like `.?*()`).

```
>>> template = "First, @action; (Second, Foobar...)"
>>> re_template = re.sub(r"\\@(\w+)", r"(?P<\g<1>>.*)", re.escape(template))
>>> print(re_template)
First\,\ (?P<action>.*)\;\ \(Second\,\ Foobar\.\.\.\)
```